# How can I distinguish threads from processes if I don't know pids in Lunix?

Tags: linux

As I understand in Linux, there are processes and lightweight processes called threads. Each of them has its own pid. With the help of the command pstree -p | grap filename, we can find out the pids of the process and threads. Each process has its own pid and it can spawn many streams with pids.

But how to determine without a command that we are dealing with a thread or a process? I tried to figure it out and found out that there is a thread_group field in file task_struct that allows you to do this.